# How to show a plot in a tooltip with Shiny

Tags: r, plot, tooltip, shiny, mouseover

I'm building a Shiny app using ggvis, and I need to show a plot (a bar chart, for example) in a tooltip.

So basically, when a user clicks one of the points in the main plot I want a tooltip (or something of the sort) to display a new plot with extra information.

Is it possible to do this with Shiny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shiny demo at: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html shows code where clicking on (or near) a point produces text output, you could modify that to create the second graph instead.  I don't know how to do it like a tool tip, but this would produce the graph next to, or just below the graph being clicked on.  The example uses ggplot2 rather than ggvis, so I don't know how that would change things.

Comment: That's probably what I'll do if I can't get the plot to show inside the tooltip. However, the person I'm doing this for would prefer the plot to be inside the tooltip, so I'm trying to find out if it's possible.

Comment: @Andromeda, if you cannot find a better tooltip solution, then you could possibly imitate a tooltip by redrawing the plot with a subplot of the barchart at the point clicked using the `subplot` function from the TeachingDemos package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I followed your initial advice and created the second graph next to the graph being clicked on. It actually looks quite nice.